# key_down event of DateTimePicker when Press Entered

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

I am using DateTimePicker to select date and store in DataGridView. 
However when the date is current date, I do not want user to select date and just press enter and get the current date and store in datagridview.

When user press enters on datetimepicker (thinking it's a current date) that I do not need to select any date. The date appears blank in datagridview.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can't you populate today's date as default from viewmodel? User would not even have to press any key.

Comment: I want to check if the date time has been changed then use the date time that has been changed and if not then use the current date time on Press Entered on datetimepicker so there is no blank data in datagridview.

Comment: It is not very likely that the user knows he's supposed to press the Enter key, not without a manual.  Much more likely he'll press the Tab key or presses an OK button or closes the window with the DTP since nothing needs to be changed.  Just initialize the cell to DateTime.Now, use the DTP's ValueChanged event to update it.  Now you don't care at all what the user did.

Comment: I am using DateTime.Now to show the current date time in DateTimeValue Picker, that hits the date value change event. 

secondly if the date is present date time, the user just hits enter and moves on, and if the date is not present he will make change to the date. 

if the date has not been changed then use the current date and time if the value has been changed then use the value changed date time.